# MVC Dependency Injection Object Reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: model-view-controller, azure

I wonder if anyone can explain the syntax in one line of this snippet of code:
below doBgProcess function when i am calling from the controller class its working fine but when i am trying to call it from worker role inside OnStart() function so its throwing exception "Object Reference not set to instance of an object"

```
    [Dependency]
    public IMembershipService IMemberhipSvcInst { get; set; }

    [Dependency]
    public IBenchmarkService IBenchmarkSvcInst { get; set; }
    #endregion
    public DashboardProcess()
    {
        //Resolving Dependency
       IMemberhipSvcInst = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMembershipService>();

    }

 public bool doBgProcess(Guid userProfileId)
    {

            if (userProfileId != null && userProfileId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                IMemberhipSvcInst.GetAllUserEmails();
            }
          return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Web Role (which contains the Controller) and Worker Role run on different machines. So in order for the DependencyResolver to work correctly you probably do the required initialization in the **Global.asax**.

Now, if you want to use that same DependencyResolver in your WorkerRole.cs (which is a different machine) or in your WebRole.cs (which is a different process), you will also need to initialize your IoC Container / DependencyResolver in the OnStart of the Web/WorkerRole.cs